# Add link to CMS page from admin panel magento

Tags: magento

How to add link to CMS from product description part with admin panel.

Answer (score 6):

You can add relative a link in the product description like this:

```
<a href="{{store url="page_identifier_here"}}#something">Anchor text here</a>
```

But in order for this to work you need to allow store (media and skin) directives in the description. This can be enabled from `System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend->Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories`. Set the field to yes and clear the cache.

Answer (score 4):

Place the anchor tag with href as below:

```
href="{{store url='about-magento-demo-store'}}"
```

Replace "about-magento-demo-store" with cms page code.

Comment: about us just the example ... reality i want to go to faq

Comment: what is the url of your faq page?

Comment: if the code of faq page is "faq" ,  href="{{store url='faq'}}" will do.

Comment: still does not work ... i want to put the href on product description when you add product. yes url key = "faq"

Comment: Please see screenshot  http://screencast.com/t/PYQ09cTAcV  .I did in same way it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can normally place an anchor tag to give any link in the Product Description section or you can use the WYSIWYG editor also by clicking on the WYSIWYG editor button just below it.

[image]

Comment: I want to add from CMS one ... not link from the outside ... how is it?

Comment: you mean, you want to add a link to a CMS page?

Comment: no. add link to product description, redirect to CMS page like about us

Comment: <a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}faq#washable"> I have already tried but it failed

Comment: <a href="{{store url='faq'}}">Link</a>

Comment: still does not work ... i want to put the href on product description when you add product.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{{store url='aboutus'}}">About US</a>
```

here about us is just example link you can add your cms page link with just replace with aboutus

hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. Just this href="/faq#washable"

Thanks guys :)

Comment: This may work on some servers, but if you have magento installed in a subfolder it won't work.